# PyCharm 2021.1 Community Edition auto import Django CASCADE

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I upgraded PyCharm Community Edition to 2021.1 a few days ago.

But I found it can't resolve some Django auto import correctly now.

For example, I set CASCADE as on_delete for one ForeignKey, it should suggest me to import django.db.models.CASCADE, but it suggest tkinter.CASCADE instead.

[image]

Comment: Finally, I downgrade to 2020.3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `models.CASCADE`. Here you have an example:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=False, blank=False)
    curricular_program = models.ForeignKey(CurricularProgram, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: No need to, if I import CASCADE.